# Android: Send 'waiting' string data to database after clicked submit button

Tags: java, android, mysql

From my question, I want to submit all data filled by the user at a database's table named `"mysuggestion"`. All the column at the table filled with user's input data except for column `"status"` and `"comment"` due to there's no user input for both "status" and "comment". These two columns need to fill with words "waiting".

How can it be done? Below is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_suggestion);

    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvTitle = viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText("CONFIRMATION");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    txtName = findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtBadgeID = findViewById(R.id.txtBadgeID);
    txtPosition = findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);
    txtDepartment = findViewById(R.id.txtDepartment);
    txtFactory = findViewById(R.id.txtFactory);

    //getting the current user
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

    //setting the values to the textviews
    txtName.setText(user.getName());
    txtBadgeID.setText(user.getBadgeid());
    txtPosition.setText(user.getPosition());
    txtDepartment.setText(user.getDepartment());
    txtFactory.setText(user.getFactory());

    etReviewer = findViewById(R.id.etReviewer);
    etTitle = findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etYear = findViewById(R.id.etYear);
    etMonth = findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
    etSuggestWill = findViewById(R.id.etSuggestWill);
    etPresent = findViewById(R.id.etPresent);
    etDetails = findViewById(R.id.etDetails);
    etBenefit = findViewById(R.id.etBenefit);
    imgAttach = findViewById(R.id.imgAttach);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String reviewer =  sharedPreferences.getString("reviewer",DEFAULT);
    String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title",DEFAULT);
    String year = sharedPreferences.getString("year",DEFAULT);
    String month =  sharedPreferences.getString("month",DEFAULT);
    String suggestionwill =  sharedPreferences.getString("suggestionwill",DEFAULT);
    String present =  sharedPreferences.getString("present",DEFAULT);
    String details = sharedPreferences.getString("details",DEFAULT);
    String benefit =  sharedPreferences.getString("benefit",DEFAULT);
    String photo = sharedPreferences.getString("photo",DEFAULT);
    String status = sharedPreferences.getString("status",DEFAULT);
    String comment = sharedPreferences.getString("comments",DEFAULT);

    etReviewer.setText(reviewer);
    etTitle.setText(title);
    etYear.setText(year);
    etMonth.setText(month);
    etSuggestWill.setText(suggestionwill);
    etPresent.setText(present);
    etDetails.setText(details);
    etBenefit.setText(benefit);
    imgAttach.setImageBitmap(base64ToBitmap(photo));

}

public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String encodedString) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString , 0,
            decodedString.length);
    return bitmap;
}

public void submit(View v ) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Submit");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to submit this suggestion?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            save();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ConfirmSuggestion.this, Submitted.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void save() {
    final String name = txtName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String badgeid = txtBadgeID.getText().toString().trim();
    final String position = txtPosition.getText().toString().trim();
    final String department = txtDepartment.getText().toString().trim();
    final String factory = txtFactory.getText().toString().trim();
    String reviewer = etReviewer.getText().toString().trim();
    reviewer = reviewer.split("-")[0]; // 004
    final String title = etTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String year = etYear.getText().toString().trim();
    final String month = etMonth.getText().toString().trim();
    final String suggestionwill = etSuggestWill.getText().toString().trim();
    final String present = etPresent.getText().toString().trim();
    final String details = etDetails.getText().toString().trim();
    final String benefit = etBenefit.getText().toString().trim();

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgAttach.getDrawable();
    final String photo = bitmapToBase64(drawable.getBitmap());

    save1(name, badgeid, position, department, factory, reviewer, title, year, month,
            suggestionwill, present, details, benefit,photo,status, comment);
}

public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
    String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImageString ;
}

private void save1(String name, String badgeid, String position, String department, String factory, String reviewer,
                      String title, String year, String month, String suggestionwill, String present, String details,
                      String benefit, String photo, String status, String comment) {

    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();
    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).userLogin(new User(user.getId(),name, badgeid, position, department, factory, reviewer,
             title,  year,  month,  suggestionwill,  present,  details,
             benefit,  photo, status, comment));

    class saveSuggest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("name", params[0]);
            data.put("badgeid", params[1]);
            data.put("position", params[2]);
            data.put("department", params[3]);
            data.put("factory", params[4]);
            data.put("reviewer", params[5]);
            data.put("title", params[6]);
            data.put("year", params[7]);
            data.put("month", params[8]);
            data.put("suggestionwill", params[9]);
            data.put("present", params[10]);
            data.put("details", params[11]);
            data.put("benefit", params[12]);
            data.put("photo", params[13]);
            data.put("status", params[14]);
            data.put("comment", params[15]);

            String result = requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_SAVE, data);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ConfirmSuggestion.this, "Saving..", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    saveSuggest sl1 = new saveSuggest();
    sl1.execute(name, badgeid, position, department, factory, reviewer, title, year, month,
            suggestionwill, present, details, benefit, photo, status, comment);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are fetching **status** and **comment** data from `SharedPreferences` set their default value "**waiting**" as follow -

```
String status = sharedPreferences.getString("status","waiting");
String comment = sharedPreferences.getString("comments","waiting");
```

I hope its work for you. Thank you

Comment: @WanDila just replace `String status = sharedPreferences.getString("status",DEFAULT);
    String comment = sharedPreferences.getString("comments",DEFAULT);` with above two lines

Comment: the how about at save() function?

Comment: save1(name, badgeid, position, department, factory, reviewer, title, year, month,
            suggestionwill, present, details, benefit,photo,status, comment);

the "status" and "comment" red color sir. please help

Comment: move your mouse there it will tell you reason why its showing red